# Rails 3, creating views of one controller within a view of another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails app that involves user, project, and thread models. A user can create or access projects and create threads regarding that project. So, a user might visit a project page and choose a 'create thread' option from the menu. I would like the views for the 'new' and 'show' actions of the Threads controller to be displayed within the 'show' view for the project.

I've only been working with Rails for the past three or four days, so my current solution is really inefficient.

I create a link to the 'new' form for a Thread in a project page in this way:

```
<%= link_to "Create Thread", {controller: 'projects', action: 'show',
newthread: true} %>
```

The project's 'show' action stores the @newthread value, and when the project page is rendered, it checks whether @newthread has been set and if so, shows the form to create a new thread.

I can create new threads in this way, but when there is an error in the form, I'm not sure how to render the project page with the thread form and its error messages.

How can I solve this particular issue? Or, is there a better way of organizing the two resources so that the views for the Thread controller are always displayed within the 'show' view of a project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option in this case is to work with nested routes.

Take a look here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

You can use the show view of the project to display the threads related to it, using a simple looping.

For example:

project controller:

```
def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @threads = @project.threads.all
end
```

show view:

```
<% @threads.each do |thread| %>
...
<% end %>
```

I hope it helps...